# javafx - Dynamically resize node from within

Tags: java, javafx

I want to create simple gridPane, which would change its size after clicking a button. I have this code:

```
 public class NewSimScene extends GridPane{

    Button testButton;
    public NewSimScene(){
        setPrefSize(500, 500);

        testButton = new Button("TEST");
        testButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                Node source = (Node) t.getSource();
                NewSimScene pane = (NewSimScene) source.getParent();
                pane.setPrefSize(100, 100);
                pane.setMaxSize(100, 100);
            }
        });


        getChildren().add(testButton);
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging, I can see that prefHeight and prefWidth values are changed, but there isn't any change in pane appearance. What could be a problem? 
I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm running this pane in a separate scene, triggered from MenuBar.

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue in your code, the Grid Pane's getting re-sized. Please have a look at the following code and feel free to comment if you are looking for something else !

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        GridPane grid = new NewSimScene();
        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(grid);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public class NewSimScene extends GridPane {

        Button testButton;

        public NewSimScene() {
            setPrefSize(500, 500);
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: palegreen;");
            testButton = new Button("TEST");
            testButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    Node source = (Node) t.getSource();
                    NewSimScene pane = (NewSimScene) source.getParent();
                    pane.setPrefSize(100, 100);
                }
            });
            getChildren().add(testButton);
        }
    }
}
```